# NSDictionary in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this following code :

```
NSAssert(dst, @"sdiasiosadiodasio");

// Add to a list so that we don't lose the references
[layersToDsts setObject:dst forKey:layer];

NSLog(@"The key is %lu", layer);                

for (Bit *layer in [layersToDsts allKeys])
{
    BitHolder *dst = [layersToDsts objectForKey:layer];

    NSLog(@"My added key is %lu", layer);

    NSAssert(dst, @"ddddd");
}
```

layersToDsts is a mutable `NSDictionary`. I'm trying to use the address of an object as the key, mapping to another object.

The code worked on iOS 5. For some reason, the code gives

```
The key is 484196128
My added key is 484253328
Assertion failure in -[Animator animateImpl:] 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ddddd'
```

Obviously, the object I added to the dictionary can't be retrieved. The object isn't nil. Why the mapping key is another address?? The code worked perfectly on iOS 5....

Comment: But my code worked in iOS 5...

Comment: @StevenFisher I disagree this is a duplicate... s/he's not asking about keys being copied, s/he's asking why the code fails and clearly doesn't realize that keys are copied.

Comment: Hmm. Fair enough. Still, that copy is the reason. Any code that requires keys in a dictionary not be copied shouldn't work in any version of iOS. I think we'd have to see the definition of `Layer` to figure this out.

Comment: @Kinderchocolate It depends on what layer exactly is... but there are some optimizations where certain classes, when copy, give you the same reference because they're immutable. You can't depend on this optimization, however. You need to use something other than whatever this "layer" is, you can't simply use object addresses as keys. Whatever this layer is, however, when it's copied it's obviously capable of having the copied value return NO on `-isEqual:`

Comment: @Kinderchocolate Then, unless you've defined it properly, `-isEqual:` is based on the address of the object in memory and may change on the copy. Fix your `-isEqual:` implementation and your `-hash` implementation to return the correct values after being copied.

Comment: What'd be the best way to fix the error? Layer has nothing defined other than properites.

Comment: Write an `isEqual:`. Also, a `hash`. You know what properties `Layer` has better than we. :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I always thought the dictionary simply hashed based on the raw address.

Comment: It's *probably* (though not certainly) a mistake to use a complex object for a key. Can you use something simpler?

Comment: (For anyone reading this later, I deleted my own suggestion that this was a duplicate. I didn't realize how bare deleting a comment would look.)

Comment: Well, my object is CALayer. I can't use it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CALayer does not implement the NSCopying protocol and so can not be used as a key, use the address of the CALayer and turn it into an NSNumber you ay alternatively be able to use the name property on CALayer.

Comment: NSValue is far better suited to this task.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an object address as the key, you should create an object that contains that address. For example

```
[layersToDsts setObject:dst forKey:[NSValue valueWithPointer:layer]];
```

However I **STRONGLY** discourage you from doing it. You should instead come out with a proper key and not depend on any specific object address.